# Time difference between rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

In a **mysql** database (ver.5.7.15) I've got the following table named `operation_list` containing the following data: **id** (*autoincrement integer*, *primary key*), **operation_date_time** (*datetime*), **operation** (*enumerated values*: **START**,**STOP**), so the table looks like that:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------+
| id   | operation_date_time | operation |
+------+---------------------+-----------+
|    1 | 2000-01-01 06:30:45 | START     |
|    2 | 2000-01-01 07:45:00 | STOP      |
|    3 | 2000-01-01 08:18:12 | START     |
|    4 | 2000-01-01 11:23:58 | STOP      |
|    5 | 2000-01-01 15:45:01 | START     |
|    6 | 2000-01-01 19:01:33 | STOP      |
+------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Now, assuming that the first row is always a START, the last ROW is always a STOP, the STOP is always placed after a START, I need to retrieve the time difference between START and STOP in seconds. Hence, I need to write an SQL that would produce the following recordset:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------+
| id   | operation_date_time | duration  |
+------+---------------------+-----------+
|    1 | 2000-01-01 06:30:45 | 4455      |
|    3 | 2000-01-01 08:78:12 | 11146     |
|    5 | 2000-01-01 15:45:01 | 11792     |  
+------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Where 4455 is equivalent to 1 hour, 14 minutes and 15 seconds, 
11146 is equivalent to 3 hours, 5 minutes and 46 seconds,
11792 is equivalent to 3 hours, 16 minutes and 32 seconds, and so on.

What's the best way to do it in a single SQL statement without creating additional tables or dedicated scripting?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works IN mysql 5.X

But it is uglier as in 8.0

```
SELECT
   MIN(id) id
  ,MIN(`operation_date_time`) `operation_date_time`
  ,MAX(diff) duration  
FROM
(SELECT 
  id
  , IF(`operation` = 'START', 0,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`operation_date_time`,  @datetime))) diff
  ,IF(`operation` = 'START',  @count := @count + 1,@count := @count) groupby
  ,@datetime := `operation_date_time` `operation_date_time`
 FROM
  (SELECT * FROM timetable ORDER by `operation_date_time` ASC) t1, (SELECT @datetime := NOW()) a,
   (SELECT @count := 0) b) t2
GROUP by groupby;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE timetable (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `operation_date_time` VARCHAR(19),
>   `operation` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO timetable
>   (`id`, `operation_date_time`, `operation`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2000-01-01 06:30:45', 'START'),
>   ('2', '2000-01-01 07:45:00', 'STOP'),
>   ('3', '2000-01-01 08:18:12', 'START'),
>   ('4', '2000-01-01 11:23:58', 'STOP'),
>   ('5', '2000-01-01 15:45:01', 'START'),
>   ('6', '2000-01-01 19:01:33', 'STOP');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>    MIN(id) id
>   ,MIN(`operation_date_time`) `operation_date_time`
>   ,MAX(diff) duration  
> FROM
> (SELECT 
>   id
>   , IF(`operation` = 'START', 0,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`operation_date_time`,  @datetime))) diff
>   ,IF(`operation` = 'START',  @count := @count + 1,@count := @count) groupby
>   ,@datetime := `operation_date_time` `operation_date_time`
>  FROM
>   (SELECT * FROM timetable ORDER by `operation_date_time` ASC) t1, (SELECT @datetime := NOW()) a,
>    (SELECT @count := 0) b) t2
> GROUP by groupby;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | operation_date_time | duration
> -: | :------------------ | -------:
>  1 | 2000-01-01 06:30:45 |     4455
>  3 | 2000-01-01 08:18:12 |    11146
>  5 | 2000-01-01 15:45:01 |    11792
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=12db1371b5ca0d3ff52e5dae464efd64)*

Comment: Just finished testing on the destination table that is quite more complex than the structure in example. It works fine with good performance, it's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions to get the ending time.  I am going to use a cumulative conditional min:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(second, operation_date_time, stop_dt) as diff_seconds
from (select t.*,
             min(case when operation = 'STOP' then operation_date_time end) over (order by operation_date_time) as stop_dt
      from t
     ) t
where operation = 'START';
```

If the data really is interleaved, then you could just use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(second, operation_date_time, stop_dt) as diff_seconds
from (select t.*,
             lead(operation_date_time) over (order by operation_date_time) as stop_dt
      from t
     ) t
where operation = 'START';
```

EDIT:

In MySQL pre-8.0:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(second, operation_date_time, stop_dt) as diff_seconds
from (select t.*,
             (select min(t2.operation_date_time)
              from t t2
              where t2.operation = 'STOP' and
                    t2.operation_date_time > t.operation_date_time
             ) as stop_dt
      from t
     ) t
where operation = 'START';
```

Comment: Thank you, but using this statement I get error around 'over' keyword. 
I'm using MySQL version 5.7.15.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT operation_date_time,DURATION FROM (
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(SECOND,operation_date_time,LEAD(operation_date_time)OVER(ORDER BY ID)) AS DURATION FROM PRACTICE
)A
WHERE operation='START'

Comment: such functions are not supported in MySQL version 5.7.15

Comment: @PowerEngineering That's the reason why proper tagging on your questions are a very crucial part of getting the right answers.  Someone provided 2 solutions that are worthless to you.

Comment: @Eric I added the MySQL version in the description text. The version of MySQL, as far as I understood, cannot be added to the tags.